# Constant's value given by a non-intrinsic function

Tags: function, fortran

In Fortran, is there a way to initialize my named constant at compilation time using a function of other constants, other than the intrinsic functions?

I want to calculate a value using my own function and then use this value to declare the size of an array, such as in my attempt below.

```
integer function factorial(n)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer :: i, ans
    ans=1
    do i=1,n
        ans=ans*i
    end do
    factorial = ans
end function Factorial

integer function binomial(n,k)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n, k
    integer :: factorial
    binomial = Factorial(n)/factorial(n-k)/factorial(k)
end function binomial

program main
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: m=10, n=3
    integer :: binomial
    integer, parameter :: sz=binomial(m,n)
    complex, dimension(sz) :: hamiltonian
    ...
end program main
```

Or do I have have to calculate this value myself and write it explicitly in the code ?

Comment: Please use tag fortran. Do you really want the old Fortran 90 only? The rules have changed since then slightly, although still not enough for you.

Comment: Sorry about this, it is my first question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to know, the Fortran standard prohibits calculations, at compile time, beyond what intrinsic routines are capable of.  If you really must make those calculations at compile time then a hack like this might appeal to you:

```
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(20), PARAMETER :: ints = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, &
       11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: m=10, n=3
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: sz = PRODUCT(ints(1:m))/PRODUCT(ints(1:m-n))/&
       PRODUCT(ints(1:n))
  COMPLEX, DIMENSION(sz) :: hamiltonian
```

This compiles, and executes, correctly.  If you confine yourself to 64-bit  integers the array `ints` doesn't need to go larger than 20.

Oh, in passing, don't use `size` as the name of a parameter, it's already the name of a useful intrinsic function.

Then again, you could just compute the factorials yourself and write:

```
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(20), PARAMETER :: factorial = [1,2,6,24,...]
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: m=10, n=3
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: sz = factorial(m)/factorial(m-n)/factorial(n)
  COMPLEX, DIMENSION(sz) :: hamiltonian
```

and be done with it.

Comment: @AdrienBolens You may want to consider accepting the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work